# How does 'envisager de' presuppose nothing situational, but 'hésiter à' does?

Tags: semantics, french, prepositions

<sub>Source: p 177, *French prepositions à and de
in infinitival complements, 
A pragma-semantic analysis* (2008) by Lidia Fraczak, as part of *Adpositions ; Pragmatic, semantic and syntactic perspectives*  (2008) edited by D Kurzon, S Adler</sub>

> **The use of *envisager de* (“to consider”) does not seem, as with *essayer de* (“to
>   try”), to be conditioned by a situational presupposition** either, in spite of the presence
>   of the preposition *de*. In the following sentence:
>
> (6) *Paul envisage de déménager.*    
>   ‘Paul is considering moving out.’
>
> the speaker informs the addressee about Paul’s (possible) plan, without calling on
>   any presupposed information about it, whereas such a presupposition might be
>   necessary with the use of *hésiter à* (“to hesitate”):
>
> (7) *Paul hésite à déménager*.    
>   ‘Paul is hesitating about moving out.’

I do not understand the (bolded) first sentence above. How does *envisager de* presuppose nothing situational? Surely, it must presuppose the (mental) ability to envisagement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it to mean that (7) implies that the fact that Paul has been thinking about moving out is not new information.